# pandas : Encontrar todas las combinaciones y cuantas veces estas se repiten

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un archivo .csv que contiene un dataframe parecido al siguiente:

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1]],columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])`

La diferencia es que el archivo .csv tiene 500 filas. Quiero encontrar las todas las combinaciones posibles solo en las columnas b,c,d,e y contar cuantas veces se repite cada una para obtener algo asi:

```
[1,0,1,0] : 1
[1,1,1,1] : 2
[0,0,1,1] : 1
```

Esto es lo que he logrado pero obtengo errores al accesar las columnas b,c,d,e. Si encuentran otra manera de hacerlo agradezco la ayuda.

```
import pandas as pd
from  itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1]],columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
#acceso a las columnas b,c,d,e
col = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4]]
print(df)
print(col)#este es el dataframe con el que quiero encontrar las combinaciones

# Obtener combinaciones de 4 numeros de las columnas b,c,d,e
cc = list(combinations(df.col, 5))

# Agregar combinaciones a una lista
tmp_list = []

for columns in cc:
    tmp_list.append(list(zip(df[col[0]], df[col[1]])))


tmp_list.append(list(zip(df.b, df.c, df.d, df.e)))

#Aplanar la lista
flat_list = [item for sublist in tmp_list for item in sublist]

print(['{0}:{1}'.format(list(item), count) for item, count in Counter(flat_list).items()])
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad. Haz hecho una buena primer pregunta, incluyendo el código que has intentado utilizar y una descripción clara, aún así te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask] para que te familiarices con los lineamientos de [es.so] y obtener tu primer medalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma mas sencilla que se me ocurre es utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) junto con [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

Utilizando el `dataframe` de tu pregunta:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1]],columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
print(df.groupby(['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], as_index=False).size())
```

Esto devuelve:

```
   b  c  d  e  size
0  0  0  1  1     1
1  0  1  1  0     2
2  1  0  1  0     1
3  1  1  1  1     2
```

Comment: Buen día, funciona a la perfección y lo mejor es que solo se utilizan dos líneas. Gracias!